# In the limit, do the intersection points of a string figure define a probability measure on the unit disk?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory

Let **D** = {z ∈ ℂ  |  |z| ≤ 1} denote the closed unit disk in the complex plane.

For any integer n ≥ 1 define the nth string figure **S**(n) ⊂ **D** as *the union of all n(n+1)/2 line segments that connect two nth roots of unity (which may be equal)*.

Let **I**(n) denote *the finite set of all intersection points between any two distinct line segments in the definition of **S**(n)*.

Let T(n)  =  |**I**(n)| denote the cardinality of **I**(n).

For any open subset **U** of **D**, define the ratio M<sub>n</sub>(**U**)  =  |**I**(n) ∩ **U**| / T(n).

M<sub>n</sub> provides an atomic probability measure on the Borel sets of **D**.

Finally, define M(**U**)  =  lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> M<sub>n</sub>(**U**).

**Questions**:

- Does this limit exist for every open **U** ⊂ **D**?
- If so, does it define a countably additive probability measure on the Borel sets of **D** ?
- If it does, can this measure be defined by the integration of some density function on **D**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all three questions. The limit measure is obtained by applying your procedure to the normalized Lebesgue measure on the boundary circle instead of the uniform distributions on the sets of roots.

Comment: Aha. I suppose that if the unit circle C = ∂D is given the uniform probability measure, then the map defined as f : C^4  →  D — given by taking (x,y,z,w) to the intersection P ∈ D of the line segments [x,y] and [z,w] — can be used to define the density d(P) at P as the 2-dimensional measure of the 2-torus in C^4 that is the inverse image by f of the point P.

Comment: Yes. As for an explicit formula for the density one has to be a bit more careful though - one also has to take into account how these preimage 2-tori foliate the original 4-torus.

Comment: I am tempted to suggest that no special care is needed. If  is the 2-form on the 4-torus C^4 that gives the natural metric on each preimage 2-torus, and if  denotes the probability measure on D (1/π times Lebesgue measure), then isn't it true that f*() ∧  gives the probability product measure on C^4 ?

Comment: This situation is clearly more subtle than I expected. Clearly special care *is* needed beyond just blindly integrating over the 2-disk D the 2-volume of f^(-1)(x) (as a surface in C^4) times the natural volume form of D ... and expecting to get the 4-volume of C^4, as even the simplest counterexamples show.